# Why do some Jupyter Notebook output cells render with an output prompt (i.e. Out[4]:) and some don't?

Tags: python, selenium, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am having a hard time figuring out why the output of some code cells are given an output prompt identifier, and some others aren't.

I have a notebook with a number of cells that generate interactive plots using bokeh. After converting the notebook to HTML with nbconvert, the labeled outputs are represented with a tag like this:

```
<div class="output_area">
    <div class="prompt output_prompt">
            Out[13]:
```

and the unlabeled outputs are represented like this:

```
<div class="output_area">
        <div class="prompt">
```

In both cases, the output is rendered as usual, but the red "Out[n]:" tag is missing in the second case. What causes this difference?

For context, I have a large number of these notebooks, and I'm trying to scrape the figures from them so I can generate reports with .png images of the figures in .docx format for general consumption. I'm using the output prompts as handles go grab these images with selenium. This works fine when there's an output_prompt there, but breaks (no image is captured) if there is no value linking the output to its place in the notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer may lie in HOW you are rendering these tags. In short, I've found that you get the Out[] label when you don't tell the notebook how to render. Image below shows different ways of displaying HTML using ipywidgets.   [image: this image]   Don't know if it is directly applicable to you but hopefully it helps.